# Name for property of "infinite distance" for tabs at top

Tags: tabs, browser, hci, fittslaw

I recall that there is a technical term for the property of browser tabs at the top of the browser window having "infinite distance" for the user's mouse pointer movement, but I cannot recall what the proper term is.

### Examples:

The placement of browser tabs at the top of the page was popularized by Google Chrome:

[image]

IE 11 does *not* have this property: the tabs are along the address bar, so the user cannot just "throw" their mouse pointer at the top of the page, and must instead carefully select the tab, avoiding moving the pointer too far up.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general name of this technique is the **"Infinite Width" element**.

According to the [Fitts' Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitts%27s_law), there are two parameters which affects the **time** of reaching a target: a **distance**, and a **width**:

[image]
[image]

Actually, the tabs in full-screen Chrome have infinite height, so you can use more specific name of the technique: "Infinite Height".
[image]

Still, the "Infinite Width" has better match to the Fitts's formulae.